# VBA runtime error -2147188720 Object does not exist powerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to write VBA code for a professional PowerPoint presentation with images about the history of high-speed steel HSS.

I am trying to run a VBA code through PowerPoint which creates multiple powerpoint files . However, I get a runtime error everytime the loop increments. The error appears in  **Set shape = pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(bildPfad, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 100, 100)**

```vb
Sub ErstelleHSSPräsentation()
    ' PowerPoint-Anwendung öffnen
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = msoTrue ' PowerPoint-Anwendung sichtbar machen
    
    ' Neue Präsentation erstellen
    Dim pptPräsentation As Object
    Set pptPräsentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    
    ' Slide 1: Gliederung
    FügeSlideHinzu pptPräsentation, "Gliederung"
    
    ' Slide 2: Hinführung
    FügeSlideHinzu pptPräsentation, "Hinführung"
    
    ' Slide 3: Geschichte und Entwicklung von HSS
    FügeSlideHinzu pptPräsentation, "Geschichte und Entwicklung von HSS"
    
    ' Slide 4: Eigenschaften von HSS
    FügeSlideHinzu pptPräsentation, "Eigenschaften von HSS"
    
    ' Slide 5: Herstellung
    FügeSlideHinzu pptPräsentation, "Herstellung"
    
    ' Slide 6: Einsatzbereiche von HSS
    FügeSlideHinzu pptPräsentation, "Einsatzbereiche von HSS"
    
    ' PowerPoint-Anwendung aktiv schließen
    pptApp.Quit
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub FügeSlideHinzu(pptPräsentation As Object, slideTitel As String)
    ' Neues Slide hinzufügen
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Set pptSlide = pptPräsentation.Slides.Add(pptPräsentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText)
    
    ' Titel des Slides setzen
    pptSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = slideTitel
    
    ' Inhalt des Slides setzen
    Select Case slideTitel
        Case "Geschichte und Entwicklung von HSS"
            pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hier kommt der Text zur Geschichte und Entwicklung von HSS."
            ' Bild einfügen
            FügeBildEin pptSlide, "Pfad_zum_Bild1.jpg"
            
        Case "Eigenschaften von HSS"
            pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hier kommt der Text zu den Eigenschaften von HSS."
            ' Bild einfügen
            FügeBildEin pptSlide, "Pfad_zum_Bild2.jpg"
            
        Case "Herstellung"
            pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hier kommt der Text zur Herstellung von HSS."
            ' Bild einfügen
            FügeBildEin pptSlide, "Pfad_zum_Bild3.jpg"
            
        Case "Einsatzbereiche von HSS"
            pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hier kommt der Text zu den Einsatzbereichen von HSS."
            ' Bild einfügen
            FügeBildEin pptSlide, "Pfad_zum_Bild4.jpg"
            
        Case Else
            ' Standardtext für andere Folien
            pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hier kommt der Text für diesen Slide."
    End Select
End Sub

Sub FügeBildEin(pptSlide As Object, bildPfad As String)
    ' Bild einfügen
    Dim shape As Object
    Set shape = pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(bildPfad, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

- The ppt file is created by below code. It is `un-saved` file.

```
Set pptPräsentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add
```

- If the ppt is a saved file, the same folder is the default location to search image file. In your case, `AddPicture` method in `Sub FügeBildEin()` can't locate the image file.

*Fix:* Include the folder when passing an argument to the subroutine `FügeBildEin` .

```
FügeBildEin pptSlide, "C:\MyImage\Pfad_zum_Bild1.jpg"
```